# Does anyone know how to fix this?

Tags: wordpress, syntax-error, parse-error

My website http://edmcginnis.net is down and showing the following:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'namespace' (T_NAMESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in /home/content/94/11030494/html/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/rest-api.php on line 15

I thought it was the contact form 7 plug-in so I disabled it via ftp. That didn't work so I updated the php to 8.0 and when that didn't work I disabled all plug-ins. Still nothing.

Can anyone help me get this site back online? I'm not really sure what to do next. Thanks

Comment: Go to this file: "/home/content/94/11030494/html/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/rest-api.php" and check what is in line 15.

Answer (score 0):

Revert all code back to how it was before it was broken, including PHP. Someone probably upgraded a PHP, WP, plugin, or accidentally edited line 15 of the CF7 rest api file. If you are unable to debug you may need to reset your code.

One last thing to remember is that if you have anything in your theme that relies on a plugin function to work it will kill your site too. Disabling plugins isn't always a good way to remove issues but it will identify them.